# Configure applications to ask for a user:pass behind a proxy

Tags: debian, networking, authentication, proxy

Here's the deal: I'm trying to set up a SQL server with Debian Linux, I managed to install Debian - but I can't get `apt-get` to work, since I'm behind a proxy.

I already managed to setup Iceweasel to work with the proxy, but that's it.

Also, I would like it to work like it did under Windows 7: every time a user tries to access the web, it should ask for a `user:pass` to authenticate the proxy.

I tried:

```
export HTTP_PROXY='http://f472:9874@cache.webad.com:80'
```

and then I tried

```
vi /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

and added the line

```
acquire::http::proxy "http://f472:9874@cache.webad.com:80";
```

It didn't work in both cases

Any suggestions?

EDIT: It did work on the second case after I added the semicolon in the end, but still, my corporate user name and password are plaintext in the config file.

Comment: Tried to make the title more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a GNOME-Keyring solution (combined with Synaptic) to this, but since it would include a graphical user environment (which your SQL server probably doesn't have), but: **how about adding a user** to the user database the proxy checks against *especially for this purpose*?

However, it might also be a solution to add the SQL server to a kind of DMZ-subnet, i.e., servers that are supposed to be allowed to access the internet without the proxy.  (Tried using *FTP*, btw?)

(If you're not in charge of user accounts, describing your problem to the ones in charge will probably make them happily agree that a new user is needed for this.)